# Change color of characters if they exceeded the certain limit in textarea

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material, textarea

I have added textarea to my angular form and I would like to limit the user input length here (let's say 1000 characters). Instead of using maxLength (which doesn't let you enter more than the specified limit) and I would like to mark the characters (for example, change the color to the red) which exceeded the limit.

```
  <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>dummy textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput formControlName="textareaFormControl" required trim="blur"
              [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    </textarea>
    <mat-error *ngIf="textareaFormControl.hasError('required')">
      {{ 'formValidation.required' | translate }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I would like to know if there are any libraries that could provide this functionality or how can I style the only part of the text.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `textarea`.

> The HTML  element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control, useful when you want to allow users to enter a sizeable amount of free-form text, for example a comment on a review or feedback form.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

but you can use a `div` with `contenteditable`. In this way you can format the text inside the `div` with some formats which indicates that some portion of text is not valid.

If you are looking for a library based on this idea, [MEDIUM.JS](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) could be a good candidate.

The code below could show how it works.

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
    <script>
        div = document.getElementById('textarea');
        var maxLength = 10;
        setInterval(function () {
            var text = div.innerHTML;
            text = text.replace('<span style="color: red">', '');
            text = text.replace('</span>', '');
            if (text.length > maxLength) {
                var normalText = text.substring(0, maxLength);
                var invalidText = text.substring(maxLength);
                var result = normalText + '<span style="color: red">' + invalidText + '</span>';
                div.innerHTML = result;
            }
            setEndOfContenteditable(div);
        }, 500);

        function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
            var range, selection;
            if (document.createRange)
            {
                range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
                range.collapse(false);
                selection = window.getSelection();
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            }
            else if (document.selection)
            {
                range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
                range.collapse(false);
                range.select();
            }
        }
    </script>
```